# Why do we need <out T> in the Network Response

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I have this network response class marked with

```
sealed class NetworkResponse<out T> {
data class Success<T>(val value: T): NetworkResponse<T>()
data class GenericError(val code: Int? = null, val error: String? = null): NetworkResponse<Nothing>()
object NetworkError: NetworkResponse<Nothing>()
class UnknownError(message: String? = "Unknown Error") : NetworkResponse<Nothing>()
}
```

If I remove "out T" and replace it with "T" following class start to fail. Can someone explain why do we need "out T"(covariant) in the above code pointer and why does the following code fails?

```
suspend fun <T> call(dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher, apiCall: suspend () -> Response<T>): NetworkResponse<T> {
return withContext(dispatcher) {
    try {
        val data = apiCall.invoke()
        if (data.isSuccessful) {
            data.body()?.let { NetworkResponse.Success(it) } ?: NetworkResponse.UnknownError()
        } else {
            NetworkResponse.NetworkError
        }
    } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
        when (throwable) {
            is IOException -> {
                Log.e("IOException", throwable.message?:"")
                NetworkResponse.NetworkError
            }
            is HttpException -> {
                Log.e("HttpException", throwable.message?:"")
                val code = throwable.code()
                val errorResponse = throwable.message()
                NetworkResponse.GenericError(code, errorResponse)
            }
            else -> {
                Log.e("GenericException", throwable.message?:"")
                NetworkResponse.GenericError(null, null)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Because of your `GenericError`, `NetworkError`, `UnknownError` is a `NetworkResponse<Nothing>` which can only be considered as a `NetworkResponse<out T>`

Comment: You should mark your sealed class as `sealed class NetworkResponse<T>`. Then on your `call` function, you need to mark its return type as `NetworkResponse<out T>`

Comment: Why should I do it this way?

Comment: You shouldn't do it that way. None of your response types are T consumers, so that would be making it more restrictive unnecessarily. Declaration site `out T` as it is above is correct.

Comment: @Tenfour04: You are right, It should not be defined as I thought.

Answer (score 1):

`NetworkResponse<Nothing>` is a subtype of `NetworkResponse<out T>`, but it is not a subtype of `NetworkResponse<T>`. It makes sense if you logically think through all the possibilities.

This allows the error subtypes of NetworkResponse to be singleton `objects` or to be more flexible data classes that are not constrained to a type.

For example, `NetworkError` has no `T` data that you can retrieve from it, so it works as a subtype of `NetworkResponse` no matter what `T` is, because you aren't going to be pulling `T`'s out of it anyway. So `NetworkError`'s single instance is a valid NetworkResponse of any type.

Conceptually, you can think of the `Nothing` type as a subtype of everything, the same way you can think of `Any` as the supertype of everything.